# Installing custom apps on a Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, apk

Does the Asus Nexus 7 allow me to create and install my own apps without using someone's app store (like Google Play or Amazon)? I want to create my own apps but not make them open for anyone else but me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Nexus 7 allows the installation of 3rd party apps.

Settings/Security/Unknown Sources

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is officially known in the Android Community as **Sideloading**.

The most "difficult" thing is to get a copy of the APK file of the app you wish to install, as you are bypassing the Google Play Store.

A very good comprehensive and informative  article written recently on **September 15th 2012** for Make Use Of entitled [*"How To Manually Install (“Side Load”) Apps On Your Android Device"*](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-manually-install-side-load-apps-on-your-android-device/) by **D.Stieben** will give you additional insight into what you wish to achieve.

Comment: As the OP is asking about developing an app, I doubt it will be "difficult" to get the apk file.

Comment: @dymutaos: Thats why I used inverted commas

Comment: I don't get one thing. A long, detailed blog entry for a process as simple as it could be expressed this way: "_1. Contect via USB. 2. Copy files to device. 3. Browse for files on device. 4. Tap to install_". Especially, sending to such "quality" blogs someone, who is developing own applications is a bit of misunderstanding -- I think that an average mobile developer knows how to handle with USB cable or copy files, right?